# How and why does "OVER(ORDER BY ...)" work in this case?

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I have a question related to a task I've been assigned:
I want to get the history of how much money there has been on an account after every change.
Let's put it this way:
Assuming there is this table 'Transactions':

```
id | account_id | change
---|------------|-------
1  |   1        |  500
2  |   2        |  300
3  |   1        | -100
4  |   2        |  100
5  |   2        | -300
```

I want this result for account_id = 1:
500
400
And this result for account_id = 2:
300
400
300

I know this can be achieved by the following because I found it and tried it:

```
SELECT SUM(change) OVER(ORDER BY id) FROM Transactions WHERE account_id = 1;
```

But since I didn't come up with this myself, but just used it, I would like to understand how and why this solution works, and would also like to know if there are some other methods for reaching the same solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad as you are asking us to explain how SQL *window functions* work and analogous methods. SO is not a general purpose forum but a Q/A for specific questions and answers. Consider reading books, vignettes, blogs, tutorials on this SQL concept as you are calculating running sum. BTW- you can calculate running sum across all accounts with partitioning: `SELECT SUM(change) OVER(PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY id) FROM Transactions`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer.